# NodeJS: How to await an asynchronous script called by runInNewContext?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm attempting to execute a custom [Script](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_constructor_new_vm_script_code_options) object using [runInNewContext](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_contextobject_options).

```
let myScript = (async () => {
  let response = await fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json');
  let user = await response.json();
})();

let vm = new Script(myScript, myScriptOptions);

let result = vm.runInNewContext(mySandbox, myContextOptions);
console.log("Done running!");
```

However, the problem I'm running into is that I'd like `runInNewContext` to actually wait until `myScript`'s asynchronous function is done running. In other words, I would like "Done running!" to be printed *after* the response has been fetched. **Is this possible? How can I achieve it please?**

Comment: I think the await goes when calling the myScript object . So try adding await right before cm. RunInNewContext...See  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Can you share the whole code please? I'm having hard time understanding the concept of this. For example in node docs code is not wrapped in a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must:

1. Make your original function return a promise
2. Await that promise when calling `runInNewContext`.

Therefore, let's say you want to return the user object:

```
let myScript = (async () => {
  let response = await fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json');
  let user = await response.json();
  return user;
})();
```

Then, add await here

```
let result = await vm.runInNewContext(mySandbox, myContextOptions);
```

as if you try to print the value of `result` it will be a promise 
so adding await will do what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Uhhh, `runInNewContext()` would need to return a promise for the `await` to do anything useful.